# How can I plot a function defined on the unit simplex in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I am trying to plot a function in *Mathematica* that is defined over the unit simplex.  To take a random example, suppose I want to plot sin(x1*x2*x3) over all x1, x2, x3 such that x1, x2, x3 >= 0 and x1 + x2 + x3 = 1.
Is there a neat way of doing so, other than the obvious way of writing something like

```
Plot3D[If[x+y<=1,Sin[x y(1-x-y)]],{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
?

What I want, ideally, is a way of plotting **only** over the simplex.  I found the website http://octavia.zoology.washington.edu/Mathematica/ which has an old package, but it doesn't work on my up-to-date version of *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get symmetric looking plots like in that package you linked, you need to figure out rotation matrix that puts the simplex into x/y plane. You can use this function below. It's kind of long because I left in the calculations to figure out simplex centering. Ironically, transformation for 4d simplex plot is much simpler. Modify `e` variable to get different margin

```
simplexPlot[func_, plotFunc_] := 
 Module[{A, B, p2r, r2p, p1, p2, p3, e, x1, x2, w, h, marg, y1, y2, 
   valid},
  A = Sqrt[2/3] {Cos[#], Sin[#], Sqrt[1/2]} & /@ 
     Table[Pi/2 + 2 Pi/3 + 2 k Pi/3, {k, 0, 2}] // Transpose;
  B = Inverse[A];

  (* map 3d probability vector into 2d vector *)
  p2r[{x_, y_, z_}] := Most[A.{x, y, z}];

  (* map 2d vector in 3d probability vector *)
  r2p[{u_, v_}] := B.{u, v, Sqrt[1/3]};

  (* Bounds to center the simplex *)
  {p1, p2, p3} = Transpose[A];

  (* extra padding to use *)
  e = 1/20;

  x1 = First[p1] - e/2;
  x2 = First[p2] + e/2;
  w = x2 - x1;
  h = p3[[2]] - p2[[2]];
  marg = (w - h + e)/2;
  y1 = p2[[2]] - marg;
  y2 = p3[[2]] + marg;

  valid = 
   Function[{x, y}, Min[r2p[{x, y}]] >= 0 && Max[r2p[{x, y}]] <= 1];
  plotFunc[func @@ r2p[{x, y}], {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}, 
   RegionFunction -> valid]
  ]
```

Here's how to use it

```
simplexPlot[Sin[#1 #2 #3] &, Plot3D]
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/simplex-plot1.png))</sub>

```
simplexPlot[Sin[#1 #2 #3] &, DensityPlot]
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/simplex-plot2.png))</sub>

If you want to see domain in the original coordinate system, you could rotate the plot back to the simplex

```
t = AffineTransform[{{{-(1/Sqrt[2]), -(1/Sqrt[6]), 1/Sqrt[3]}, {1/
      Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[6]), 1/Sqrt[3]}, {0, Sqrt[2/3], 1/Sqrt[
      3]}}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3}}];
graphics = simplexPlot[5 Sin[#1 #2 #3] &, Plot3D];
shape = Cases[graphics, _GraphicsComplex];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], GeometricTransformation[shape, t]}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/raster2.png))</sub>

Here's another simplex plot, using traditional 3d axes from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16498/traditional-axes-in-3d-mathematica-plots) and `MeshFunctions->{#3&}`, complete code [here](https://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2011/02/plotting-over-3d-simplex.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/simplex.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, @Yaroslav.  What I was really hoping for, though, was that the axes would lie along the sides of the simplex, so that we could really think of the plot as being _on the simplex itself_.  An acceptable alternative, I suppose, would be to remove the border and to label to corners x1=1, x2=1, and x3=1 (the remaining two variables implicitly being zero when the third equals one).

Comment: Thanks again @Yaroslav.  What I was imagining was a plot like your first figure above, but minus the enclosing box, and with the corners labelled appropriately.  But now you've given me all these tips I should probably try to work it out myself rather than freeriding on you!

Comment: Enclosing box is controlled by `Frame` option, you can make corner labels with `labels=Graphics[Text[#, p2r@#] & /@ IdentityMatrix@3];` Combine original plot and labels using `Show`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y (1 - x - y)], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But you can also use `Piecewise` and `RegionFunction`:

```
Plot3D[Piecewise[{{Sin[x y (1 - x - y)], 
    x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x + y <= 1}}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x + y <= 1]]
```

Comment: these give the same results as the code I posted in my original question.